# Help with Executing a method with parameters on a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method which I instantiate as follows:

```
new DatabaseHarness.MemoryStressTest().ExecuteTest("Thread 1",1,1,1)
```

What is the standard way to make this call via a thread, passing the parameters as shown above, using the threading capabilities of .NET 4?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET 4.0 way of doing it is to use a `Task`.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
  () => 
  {
    new DatabaseHarness.MemoryStressTest().ExecuteTest("Thread 1", 1, 1, 1);
  },
  TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
);
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
    new DatabaseHarness.MemoryStressTest().ExecuteTest("Thread 1",1,1,1);
});
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Since this uses a lambda for the ThreadStart, if you were to change from hardcoded parameter values ("Thread 1", 1, etc.) to variables (threadName, processId, etc.), it would complicate things, correct? So you would want to create local variables within the scope of the lambda to pass in as the parameters?

Comment: @Joel - sure, but without variables in the *question* it is hard to show correct parameterisation in the answer, ***in particular*** when talking about captured variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways of doing it. Check this link for more info: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4698-Making-Parameterized-reads-C.aspx.

First option involves creating ParameterizedThreadStart delegate, second option is creating anonymous method call that wraps your parameters (using second method may cause unwanted closures).